# Create Azure Function from Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I wonder how we can create a function from the Azure Portal UI.

On Function options, it shows the below warning:

[image]

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/540309/azure-function-portal-editing-is-disabled) thread which says there should be an option of 'Develop in Portal' but I am not able to find it

---------------Edit-1--------------

After going through "Pravallika's" answer I tried one more time to create a function from Scratch and it seems in my case only a few settings are getting created by default as compared to the screenshots presented in the answer by her:

[image]

I also created one more function and tried manually adding the settings, which are not getting created with my function by default:

[image]

Note: I have followed [This Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentshare) to configure the settings manually.

However still, I am not able to see the "develop in portal" option:

[image]

Comment: what are the options you can see in [Development environment](https://i.imgur.com/gdHQaRg.png) when you try to create the function?

Comment: I am getting only two: https://imgur.com/XfmtzJn

Comment: What is the runtime stack, OS and hosting plan of your function app?

Comment: Runtime stack-Python3.8, OS-Linux(default) and Consumption Plan, I am using a free account so most of the things are the default for me.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried creating function app with runtime stack `python 3.8` in Consumption plan:**
[image]

**Function App1: Consumption Plan:**

- Created function app in consumption hosting plan and I could see **Develop in Portal** option in the functions.

[image]

**Configuration:**

- Below are the application settings available in Configuration of function app:

[image]

As you mentioned you are using Consumption plan, updating the answer:

I have checked by deleting the settings `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` in the configuration of function app:

[image]

I couldn't see the option `Develop in portal` as shown below:

[image]

- To fix this issue:

Add the settings [WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentazurefileconnectionstring) and
[WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentshare) in the `Function app=>Settings=>Configuration=>Add Application Settings` as mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/540309/azure-function-portal-editing-is-disabled) you shared. You will be able see **Develop in portal** option and you can **create function.**

**References:**

[Create function in the Azure portal | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal#create-a-function-app)

Comment: I have updated my question based on things I have tried from your answer.

Comment: Have you given the values correctly for those settings?

Comment: From the Official Documentation, I was not able to understand which value we can set for WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE, it seems this value is assigned automatically at runtime when a file share is created, in my case I had to create a file share manually as it was not getting created automatically and I used this file share name as the value for WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE. I think I have provided all the values correctly as I tested it deploying through VSCode.

Comment: No, it's still the same.

Comment: It may be because of free account. Try creating a new function app with other hosting plans(Functions premium/App Service Plan) and check if you still face the same.

Comment: Yeah it may be due to that as one of my colleague is also facing similar issues with free account. I will check with other options now.

Comment: @kwick, Any update on the issue? Is it resolved?

Comment: Tried with "App Service Plan" last week and the issue remains the same.